# maven-client-plugin, GraalVM, Github Actions and the locale

Tags: gluon-mobile, graalvm

I am trying to use GraalVM and native-image to compile a binary using Github Actions. And I got it working so far.

But since I started including a JAR file with only _de.properties files, I am running into problems that GraalVM fails to use the correct locale to resolve a resource.

The resource in question **org.prelle.splimo.i18n.core** only exists as `org.prelle.splimo.i18n.core_de.properties`. I've read that the system locale is used to resolve the resources, that is why I tried to change the environment.

The block in the Github Actions is

```
    - name: Compile
      run:  export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8; export LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8; locale ; mvn -U -s settings.xml clean client:compile
      env: 
        LANG: de_DE
```

and the output of this is

```
Run export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8; export LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8; locale ; mvn -U -s settings.xml clean client:compile
/home/runner/work/_temp/5e196397-4957-4da6-bfa0-dcd28543ce0e.sh: line 1: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (de_DE.UTF-8): No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=de_DE
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
```

ending with

```
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:43 UTC 2020][INFO] Logging process [objdump] to file: /home/runner/work/Mondtor/Mondtor/target/client/log/process-objdump-1598564023270.log
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:44 UTC 2020][INFO] [SUB] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:52 UTC 2020][INFO] [SUB] [de.rpgframework.splittermond.mondtor.mondtormain:2770]    classlist:   7,636.69 ms,  1.18 GB
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:53 UTC 2020][INFO] [SUB] [de.rpgframework.splittermond.mondtor.mondtormain:2770]        setup:     539.93 ms,  1.18 GB
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:53 UTC 2020][INFO] [SUB] Fatal error:java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.prelle.splimo.i18n.core, locale en_US
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:53 UTC 2020][INFO] [SUB]  at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
[Thu Aug 27 21:33:53 UTC 2020][INFO] [SUB]  at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
```

It seems that all locale settings do not affect the locale used by GraalVM.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try adding this to the Client plugin: `<nativeImageArgs>
      <arg>-Duser.language=de</arg>
      <arg>-Duser.country=DE</arg>
</nativeImageArgs>`? I assume you already added `org.prelle.splimo.i18n.core` to the `bundlesList`?

Comment: @JoséPereda That indeed helped. (And yes, the resourcebundle had been added to the bundlslist)